# Numpy slicing 2 columns from 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi I am trying to slice 2 columns from a 2D numpy array but it seems that I can't get it without using a loop.
What am i missing? I am trying to get `[3 7 11]` and `[4 8 12]`.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

a=np.reshape(a,(3,4))

print a[:,2] #vgives me [ 3  7 11]
```

The only way I can do it seems to be with a loop

```
for i in range(2,4):
    print a[:,i]
```

How can I do that with pure Numpy slicing?

Comment: if you want 2nd (0-based) column to the last column you can do

    **a[:, 2:]**

elseif you want explicitly 2nd and 3rd columns, you can do

    **a[:, 2:4]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements you are trying to get with this code:

```
for i in range(2,4):
    print a[:, i]
```

correspond to that:

```
print a[:, 2:4]
```

Comment: This gives me [[3 4] [7 8] [11 12]], how can I get [3 7 11] and [4 8 12] ?

Comment: You have to transpose the result : `a[:, 2:4].T`

Comment: Thanks ! @AxelPuig  that’s what I needed :)

Comment: Or `a.T[2:4]`..